# How to use JqPlot with Rails and Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, jqplot

I am working on a simple Rails app and I am stuck. I spent a few hours trying to find ways to get this to work, but I can't. How can I get JqPlot working? It would be a great help if I can get this working. The problem is that I don't quite understand the assets pipeline and I couldn't find a good gem.

Answer (score 2):

The instructions here worked for me:

https://github.com/eightbitraptor/jqplot-rails